# apt-get -f install error

Tags: purge

My apologies...I'm new...but I seem to be running in circles with trying to do a number of things.

### Problem #1

`apt-get -f install` is returning with

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.11.0-26-generic_3.11.0-26.45_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.11.0-24-generic_3.11.0-24.42_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

### Problem #2

I am currently running on an old kernel 3.11.0-20 generic, I have tried to delete numerous other kernels to try and free up `/boot` space however two newer kernels are getting in the way with unmet dependencies of the two kernels listed above. I am unable to purge those two kernels.

```
agiles@agiles-23-1015:/boot$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.11.0-24-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'linux-image-3.11.0-24-generic' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-24-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.11.0-24-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-26-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.11.0-26-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.11.0-26-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
agiles@agiles-23-1015:/boot$
```

There in lies the circle...Please help...

Comment: Could you install those first before purging? `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.11.0-24-generic` and if that works, then purge it, or post the error message. Could you also give the full output of `apt-get -f install`?